# VLookup from excel workbook on a network drive

Tags: vba, excel-2013

Right now I have 8 different textbox controls on a UserForm that when a value is entered a macro runs to open a workbook saved on a network folder then a `VLookup` is run.  Below is the code for two of the TextBox controls and as you can see (due to my lack of coding ability); I ended up with 8 separate subs for each of the text boxes which opens up the workbook on the shared drive after  a value is entered in the text box then closes the workbook and is not very efficient.  After some research I am thinking of using `Index` and `Match` would be  a better solution, but have no familiarity with those excel functions in VBA and could use some help with getting a starting point using `Index` and `Match`, if that is a better solution.  Thank you all for your assistance.

```
  Sub b1CIF()
    Dim CustList As Workbook
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    Dim wsRR As Worksheet
    Dim bColor As Range
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response

    Msg = "OOOPS!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The CIF Number of " & LendStart.lsPBCIF.Value & " " & "is not correct or does not exist." & vbNewLine & "Please re-enter the CIF Number."
    Style = vbOKCancel + vbCritical
    Title = UCase("***CIF Data Entry Error!***")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set CustList = Workbooks.Open("L:\Deposits\Information\Customers.xlsm")
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set thisWS = thisWB.Sheets("SavedInfo")
    Set wsRR = thisWB.Sheets("RiskRating")
    Set bColor = wsRR.Range("C3")

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'   NAME GRAB
    If thisWS.Range("A2") <> "" Then
        thisWS.Range("PBName").Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.VLookup(thisWS.Range("A2").Value, CustList.Sheets("CIFMAST").Range("A1:Z50000"), 2, False)
        With LendStart.lsPBName
            .Value = thisWS.Range("PBName")
            .Visible = True
            .Locked = True
            .BackColor = bColor.Interior.Color
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 9
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
            .TabStop = False
        End With
        thisWB.Sheets("BorrInfo").Range("PB").Value = thisWS.Range("PBName")
'   TELEPHONE NUMBER GRAB
        thisWB.Sheets("BorrInfo").Range("PBPhone").Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.VLookup(thisWS.Range("A2").Value, CustList.Sheets("CIFMAST").Range("A1:Z50000"), 9, False)
    End If

    CustList.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:

    LendStart.lsPBSCIF.Value = ""
    With LendStart.lsPBName
        .Value = ""
        .Locked = True
    End With
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
    CustList.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Sub b2CIF()
    Dim CustList As Workbook
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    Dim wsRR As Worksheet
    Dim bColor As Range
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response

    Msg = "The CIF Number entered " & LendStart.lsPBSCIF.Value & " " & "is not correct." & vbNewLine & "Please re-enter the CIF Number."
    Style = vbOKCancel + vbCritical
    Title = UCase("***CIF data entry error!***")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set CustList = Workbooks.Open("L:\Deposits\Information\Customers.xlsm")
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set thisWS = thisWB.Sheets("SavedInfo")
    Set wsRR = thisWB.Sheets("RiskRating")
    Set bColor = wsRR.Range("C3")

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'   NAME GRAB
    If thisWS.Range("A3") <> "" Then
        thisWS.Range("PBSName").Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.VLookup(thisWS.Range("A3").Value, CustList.Sheets("CIFMAST").Range("A1:Z50000"), 2, False)
        With LendStart.lsPBSName
            .Value = thisWS.Range("PBSName")
            .Visible = True
            .Locked = True
            .BackColor = bColor.Interior.Color
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 9
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
            .TabStop = False
        End With
        thisWB.Sheets("BorrInfo").Range("PBS").Value = thisWS.Range("PBSName")
'   TELEPHONE NUMBER GRAB
        thisWB.Sheets("BorrInfo").Range("PBSPhone").Value = _
        WorksheetFunction.VLookup(thisWS.Range("A3").Value, CustList.Sheets("CIFMAST").Range("A1:Z50000"), 9, False)
    End If

    CustList.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:

    LendStart.lsPBSCIF.Value = ""
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
    CustList.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Switching to index/match isn't going to gain you any speed if the primary performance issue is the opening and closing of the source workbook.

Comment: Ok.  So I think what I will do is leave the 8 different subs as is for now, but continue researching ways to combine the 8 different subs I have into one.  Thanks @TimWilliams.

Comment: You can definitely combine the subs - Hopefully someone here has more free time than me right now and can make a useful suggestion.  I would begin by identifying the variable parts of each sub and extracting those into parameters you can pass in.